# Ext Ajax request not receiving response.responseText as JSON from Grails controller

Tags: json, grails, extjs4

I am having a controller in my grails application which uses HTTPBuilder to make restful call as shown in the code below:

```
import grails.converters.deep.JSON
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET


class NotificationController {

    def index() {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }

    def list()
    {
        println "in List Method of Notification Controller"
        def http1 = new HTTPBuilder("http://localhost:8082")

        // perform a GET request, expecting JSON response data
        http1.request(groovyx.net.http.Method.GET,      groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON) 
        {
            uri.path = '/Dummy/CASearchService/dummysearch/meta'

        // response handler for a success response code:
                response.success = {  resp, json ->
                println resp.statusLine
                // parse the JSON response object:
                println("json -- "+json)
                println((json as grails.converters.JSON).class)

                render json as grails.converters.JSON;      
        }
        // handler for any failure status code:
            response.failure = { resp ->
            println "Unexpected error: ${resp.statusLine.statusCode} : ${resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase}"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now, this returns a json string as response, as the println(json) returns a json string as:

```
[[_id:[machine:680383044, inc:149754531, time:1334648778000, new:false], _class:com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, form1name:EmpForm, form2name:DeptForm, form3name:HRForm, form4name:AdminForm, form5name:FSIForm], [_id:[machine:680339682, inc:-2056232867, time:1334648869000, new:false], _class:com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, form1name:IHLForm, form2name:CCDForm, form3name:AHDForm, form4name:ServicecnteraForm, form5name:ISForm]]
```

On list.gsp file under notification, i have the following Ext.Ajax call:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="ext"/>
<title>List of Notifications</title>

<script>

 Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '${createLink( action: 'list' )}',
    success: function (response){
            //Response json object
            alert("SUCCESS")
            var jsonData = (response.responseText);
            alert(jsonData)
         },
    failure: function (response){
        alert("Failure")
    }
});  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body">
  In List gsp of Notification Controller
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. After this step, when i load the browser and call NotificationController, I am getting the json string, displayed directly in the browser. Why is this happening and why is the call not going to Ajax.request.success?

   [{"_id":{"machine":680383044,"inc":149754531,"time":1334648778000,"new":false},"_class":"com.mongodb.BasicDBObject","form1name":"EmpForm","form2name":"DeptForm","form3name":"HRForm","form4name":"AdminForm","form5name":"FSIForm"},{"_id":{"machine":680339682,"inc":-2056232867,"time":1334648869000,"new":false},"_class":"com.mongodb.BasicDBObject","form1name":"IHLForm","form2name":"CCDForm","form3name":"AHDForm","form4name":"ServicecnteraForm","form5name":"ISForm"}]
2. If i change the response in the controller from 
   render json as grails.converters.JSON;
   to
   render(view: "list", contentType: "application/json")
   I am taken to the list.gsp page, but response.responseText comes as the complete html text, and not the json string. Any clue why?

Any help on this, and understanding grails controller, json, ext ajax will be appreciated.

Comment: The response you posted is not a valid JSON response.

Comment: Thanks Sha. But what gets printed on the browser, if we render json as JSON is: [{"_id":{"machine":680383044,"inc":149754531,"time":1334648778000,"new":false},"_class":"com.mongodb.BasicDBObject","form1name":"EmpForm","form2name":"DeptForm","form3name":"HRForm","form4name":"AdminForm","form5name":"FSIForm"},{"_id":{"machine":680339682,"inc":-2056232867,"time":1334648869000,"new":false},"_class":"com.mongodb.BasicDBObject","form1name":"IHLForm","form2name":"CCDForm","form3name":"AHDForm","form4name":"ServicecnteraForm","form5name":"ISForm"}]                  And this is a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I have not accustomed to grails. However, after reading your code, there is something incorrect, so I try to explain your 2 issues:

> .1: use "render json as grails.converters.JSON":

when you run the Controller, you do not specify the view to render/redirect; so the JSON string is returned and displayed on browser (i.e not yet taken to list.gsp page)

> .2: change the response in the controller from render json as grails.converters.JSON; to render a new view: "list", contentType: "application/json")

you can access the json result directly in the view, so you don't need to use Ajax here. Just echo it or do anything you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have actually resolved this problem. The problem here was, when i did a render json as JSON, i was actually trying to get the response on list.gsp, but actual call is from index.gsp. I am able to get the response.responseText on index.gsp and have sucessfully populated json object onto a ext grid panel :)